# Where does Outlook 2010 logging write to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, logging

I have enabled logging in Outlook 2010

Options > Advanced > Enable troubleshooting logging

But i dont know where these logs go.

Is the event log or some location on the file system

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Outlook 2010 on:

- Windows 7:  `c:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\Temp\Outlook Logging`
- Windows XP:  `c:\Documents and Settings\user name\Local Settings\Temp\Outlook Logging`

Reference Link: https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/What-is-the-Enable-logging-troubleshooting-option-0fdc446d-d1d4-42c7-bd73-74ffd4034af5

Answer (score 0):

It goes to the location specified for "Temp".  The default is as quoted above but if you have altered the "Temp" location, the logging is in the new location.